# Struggling to setup SFTP server on mounted HDD (client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset)

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

Attempting to setup an SFTP server on a mounted hard drive, and have followed the instructions from a bunch of tutorials, always get "client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset" on login.

I started by creating a group called sftp, then assigning a user to that group with its home directory in the HDD:

```
sudo useradd -g sftp -d /media/linux/MyHDD/NAS/USERNAME -s /sbin/nologin USERNAME-nas

sudo passwd USERNAME
```

Where USERNAME is my personal username

I then attempted to set ownership of everything above the USERNAME folder to root and the USERNAME folder to the user:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /media

sudo chown -R USERNAME:sftp /media/linux/MyHDD/NAS/USERNAME
```

Editted the sshd_config file to contain:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftp
ChrootDirectory /media/linux/MyHDD/NAS/USERNAME
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11 Forwarding no
```

Not forgetting to restart the sshd service

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

As I wanted to access this folder on my linux computer, I set the permissions to 777 for the media folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /media
```

After doing all this, when attempting to login to sftp and entering password I am greeted with:

```
sftp -P PORTNO USERNAME@IP

client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
Connection closed
```

Is this a permissions issue, or possibly an ownership issue, I don't know. I have spent a long time on this and cannot seem to figure it out, so any help would be appreciated.